# FFMPEG play in HTML while converting

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

Hello :)

I need to be able to display any popular video format (MKV, FLV, MP4,...) inside a browser WHILE converting. To do this I've turned to FFMPEG to convert any video to .ovg and spent hours on Google, forums and in documentation but I can't find a way to play the converted video real-time.

Does anyone know how you can play a video in HTML while FFMPEG is still converting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single format, especially if you want your videos played on iOS. `HLS` [is a good compromise](https://bitmovin.com/browser-capabilities/) but you'll need a player on desktop browsers. You can find HTML5/Media Source Extension (MSE) solutions like [hls.js](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/tree/master)

With `ffmpeg` you can generate a `HLS` `EVENT` playlist which is something like a combination of live and VOD: media segments are appended to the playlist as they get converted and when the input ends it remains available as VOD. It can be served via `HTTP` with any web server.

```
ffmpeg -i <input> [...] -f hls -hls_playlist_type event /path/to/html/dir/playlist.m3u8
```

`ffmpeg` supports multiple outputs and you can convert the video to other formats at the same time if you want:

`ffmpeg -i <input> [...] -f hls -hls_playlist_type event /path/to/html/dir/playlist.m3u8 \
 [...] -f <format2> <output2>`